# Exec a program on client runs a programm on server

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh

First of all I have spent over 4 hours researching this topic..

So I have a `Windows 2008 r2` root server at the moment. I connect to it via `Remote Desktop`.

Now I want to write a program that runs batch files on the server but the program is at client side, I have tried to setup an SSH server on my Windows server with `Freesshd`.

That seems to work but the programs are not shown. (In Taskmanager are they)

Is there way (prefer SSH) to let them show normally?

The goal is to restart programs (Gameservers).

My Program will work so: if I press restart server it will connect (if SSH) via Putty to the server to exec the batch file.
Or will start another program with parameters something like this:

```
Clientprogramm -ip 95.25.115.** -user Administrator -p xxxxxx C:\gameserverdir\start.bat
```

Simple and fine. I have done that already for Linux and there it isn't that hard.

So if you have an idea that can help me would be nice to know.

Both system are Windows!

Comment: Something like [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)?

Comment: Have a look at powershell http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx .
You can do something like 
`invoke-command -computername server1 -filepath C:\gameserverdir\start.bat`

Comment: yeah i have looked into it .. But there is now way to store the password as far as i see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SSH, the tool you need is plink. It's putty for command line.

Or, as indicated in comments, you can use psexec, or powershell, or vbscript, or .... BUT started programs are only "visible" in the same session from where they were started.